# The system cannot find the path specified while signing apk with a new keystore just created

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to generate a signed apk but It fails with the error:

```
C:/some/random/path/keystorename.jks: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Android is searching in the wrong path, also, i just created a new keystore, it is supposed to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Build -> Clean project` fixes this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add these info at your build.gradle (inside "android") ?
for Linux:

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            storeFile file('/home/yourPathHere/myapp.keystore')
            keyAlias 'yourAliasHere'
            keyPassword 'KeyPasswordHere'
            storePassword 'storePasswordHere'
        }
    }
```

for Windows:

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            storeFile file('c:\yourPathHere\myapp.keystore')
            keyAlias 'yourAliasHere'
            keyPassword 'KeyPasswordHere'
            storePassword 'storePasswordHere'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cleaning the project worked, it was just an Android Studio bug :)